# Timeseries forecasting by groups

Tags: r

[![Sample data][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTBF0.jpg

I need help with time series forecasting by group. I attached a sample data set below named Mydata (I couldn't fine a way to attach the file, I can send the file if need be).

So: I'm looking to forecast volume for each property and outlet using the function auto.arima:

The problem is I have to forecast for close to 150 outlets and multiple properties. I'm looking to do it all at once. Ideally I want to:

1. Group the data by property and by Outlets.
2. Transform each group into a time series.
3. Forecast for each outlet using `auto.arima` with `xreg` being segment 1 through 4

Each property have multiple outlets. so something along the line of

```r
forecast <- mydata %>% 
  group by(Property, outlet) %>% 
  ts(.$Volume) %>% 
  do(fit = auto.arima(.$volume, xreg = mydata[5:8] ) %>% 
  forecast(fit, h = 21)
```

I will be doing a daily forecast. So it I can have a table of a three week forward looking forecast for each property and each outlet, that will be great.

Comment: Hey, I am looking for something almost similar. Could you find a solution?